# reading an external file using TextIO

Tags: java, filereader

I don't understand how to use TextIO's readFile(String Filename)
Can someone please explain how can I read an external file?

```
public static void readFile(String fileName) {
  if (fileName == null) // Go back to reading standard input
     readStandardInput();
  else {
     BufferedReader newin;
     try {
        newin = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileName) );
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't open file \"" + fileName + "\" for input.\n"
                       + "(Error :" + e + ")");
     }
     if (! readingStandardInput) { // close current input stream
        try {
           in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
     }
     emptyBuffer();  // Added November 2007
     in = newin;
     readingStandardInput = false;
     inputErrorCount = 0;
     inputFileName = fileName;
  }
```

}

Comment: what exctly you don't understand?

Comment: how to read an external file. How to use this part of TextIO

Comment: Seems like you have to call `readFile("/path/to/file)` first and then use the input methods of that class. Like `getAnyChar()`, `getlnString()` or `getln()`.

Comment: My answer has apparently helped a few people in my school. I know this is an old post, but if this worked for you could you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I had to use TextIO for a school assignment and I got stuck on it too. The problem I had was that using the Scanner class I could just pass the name of the file as long as the file was in the same folder as my class.

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("data.txt");
```

That works fine. But with TextIO, this won't work;

```
TextIO.readfile("data.txt"); // can't find file
```

You have to include the path to the file like this;

```
TextIo.readfile("src/package/data.txt");
```

Not sure if there is a way to get it to work like the Scanner class or not, but this is what I've been doing in my course at school.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer (about using the correct file name) is correct, however, as a clarification, make sure that you actually use the proper file path. The file path suggested above, i.e. src/package/ will not work in all circumstances.  While this will be obvious to some, for those of you who need clarification, keep reading.

For example (and I use NetBeans), if you have already moved the file into NetBeans, and the file is already in the folder you want it to be in, then right click on the folder itself, and click 'properties'.  Then expand the 'file path' section by clicking on the three dots next to the hidden file path.  You will see the actual file path in its entirety.

For example, if the entire file path is:

*C:\Users..\NetBeansProjects\IceCream\src\icecream\icecream.dat*

Then, in the java code file itself, you can write:

```
TextIo.readfile("src/icecream/icecream.dat");
```

In other words, make sure you include the words 'src' but also everything that follows the src as well.  If it's in the same folder as the rest of the files, you won't need anything prior to the 'src'.